# I am creating a calculator in c++ which it has an undo and clear. Using stacks

Tags: c++, stack

For my assignment I need to make calculator using stacks. I got the adding subtracting multiplying part. I keno for undo I just pop the stack and for clear I can just add a 0 to the top of the stack but every time a user enters U or C the program crashes because user input is supposed to be int.

output:

```
=>1
2
+
=>3
2
-
=>1
9
*
=>9
9
/
=>1
u
=>9
c
=>0
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <stack>

using namespace std;

int add(int a, int b)
{
    int x;
    x = a + b;
    return x;
}

int sub(int a, int b)
{
    int x;
    x = a - b;
    return x;
}

int multi(int a, int b)
{
    int x;
    x = a * b;
    return x;
}

int divide(int a, int b)
{
    int x;
    x = a / b;
    return x;
}

int main()
{
    stack<int>math;
    char ASMD;
    int x = 0;
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    bool control = false;

    math.push(x);

    cout << "=> " << math.top() << endl;

    while (control == false)
    {
        cin >> b;
        cin >> ASMD;
        a = math.top();

        switch (ASMD)
        {
            case '+':
            {
                x = add(a, b);
                break;

            }
            case '-':
            {
                x = sub(a, b);
                break;
            }
            case '*':
            {
                x = multi(a, b);
                break;
            }
            case '/':
            {
                if (b != 0)
                {
                    x = divide(a, b);
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    cout << "error: can't divide my 0" << endl;
                    break;
                }

            }

            default:
            {
                control = true;
                break;
            }

        }

        math.push(x);
        cout << "=> " << math.top() << endl;

    }
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Warning: check the IO for success. Eg: `cin >> b;` should be `if (cin >> b) { use b } else { clean up and prompt user for new b }` or similar. Never count on the meatbag at the keyboard to give you good input. In fact count on the meatbag to do evil, malicious stuff.

Comment: Side note: Variables like `a`, `b`, and `x` do not describe the intent of the code very well and make it very easy to insert and not find typos. Use longer and descriptive identifiers. The time you save typing single letter identifiers can be more than consumed by the time spent solving one bug that results.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to implement a calculator, use the Shunting Yard algo. This algorithm works in the same manner as swapping a position in two arrays with the exception that instead of using a single cell as temporary storage, it utilizes a stack. The end result is to transform human readable expressions (infix notation) notation to computer executable expressions (postfix notation). For example, shunting yard will translate this infix expression "1 + 1" to "1 1 +". The postfix expression is stored in a stack and evaluated by poping the elements from the postfix stack until your reach an operator. Take the operator and apply it to the numbers already poped. That's a super brief overview so here's some more:

Rosetta Code: http://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Parsing/Shunting-yard_algorithm
Wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm

I've implemented this a few times so if you need any more help just ask!

Answer (score 0):

You are too eager in evaluating the user input with

```
 char ASMD;
 int b = 0;
 ...
 cin >> b;
 cin >> ASMD;
```

You should read it into a string first and then decide the what the next action is.

1. if the input is `'u'` or `'c'` then there is no further input.
2. if the input is convertible to an integer then you need to read the operand.
3. if the input is 'wrong' then print some sort of error message and `continue`.

You are also not popping the values off the stack. Here is an improved but not fully functional version

```
cin >> in;    

if( in == "u" ){
    std::cout << "undo not implemented\n";
    continue;
}

try{
    b = stoi( in );
} 
catch( std::invalid_argument& ){
    std::cout << "invalid input\n";
    continue;
}

a = math.top();
math.pop(); // ! need to pop here, well somewhere        
cin >> ASMD;
```

see improved version [live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/75b4b5d83eeebd28)

Answer (score 0):

You can read a string and then check if it can be converted to an int.

```
std::string input;
int inputAsInt;

if(std::cin << input) // Just to check that reading was successfull
{
    try {
        inputAsInt = std::stoi(input);
        // conversion succeeded, input was an int
    }
    catch(const std::exception &) {
        // conversion failed, the input was a string
    }
}
```

That's just a basic example, but I hope it points you in the right direction.